# Fetching data from 2 tables using SqlParameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am trying to fetch data from 2 table using Join and `SqlParameter`, but I am getting null values in my second table. I am using ASP.NET MVC.

Here are my model, controller, and view:

Model:

```
public class PersonalDetails
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FatherName { get; set; }
    public string Dob { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int StateId{ get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int CitytId { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public List<Qualifications> Qualifications { get; set; }
}

public class Qualifications
{
   public string className { get; set; }

  //  public int BoardId { get; set; }
    public string Board { get; set; }
    public double ObtainMarks { get; set; }
    public double MaxMarks { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Model for database

```
public List<PersonalDetails> showAll(int id)
{
    List<PersonalDetails> psd = new List<PersonalDetails>();

    SqlParameter[] para = new SqlParameter[]
            {
                new SqlParameter{ParameterName = "@ID",Value = id}
            };

    string query = @"sp_show_alldetails @ID";
    psd = this.Database.SqlQuery<PersonalDetails>(query, para).ToList();
    return psd;
}
```

and my controller

```
public ActionResult ShowAllDetails(int id)
{
    return View(new MyConnection().showAll(id).ToList());
}
```

View

```
@model List<DropdownBind.Models.PersonalDetails>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowAllDetails";
}

<h2>ShowAllDetails</h2>
@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>@p.Name</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    foreach (var x in p.Qualifications)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>@x.className</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
    break;
}
```

And the procedure that I am using

```
procedure sp_show_alldetails   
    @ID int  
as  
begin  
    select 
        P.ID, P.Name, P.FatherName, C.CityName as City, 
        P.EmailId, S.StateName as State,
        Q.ObtainMarks, Q.MaxMarks, Q.Year, Q.className, 
        B.BoardName as Board  
    from 
        PersonalDetails P 
    join 
        QualiFicationDetails Q on Q.ID = P.ID 
    join 
        StateMaster S on s.StateID = P.State 
    join 
        CityMaster C on C.CityID = P.City 
    join 
        BoardMaster B on B.BoardId = Q.Board 
    where 
        P.ID = @ID
end
```

Now when I run this code I have value for Personal details but I am unable to fetch the data for Qualification part, it is throwing a null exception because there is no value fetched in this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the  nice and worthy advice I will keep that in mind for the next time. :)

Comment: Replace join with "left join" for Qualification part in your query. and put the Qualification part at the last join

Comment: @NaveenChandraTiwari that makes no sense. If an inner join was restricting the results, there would be no rows returned at all, not just missing data in some fields. A left join makes it _more_ likely there will empty columns in the qualifications, if anything.

Comment: @avirk it's not clear how you are populating the `List<Qualifications>` within your PersonalDetails class? The stored proc only returns a single flat result set which will populate the principal properties of the class. It cannot populate a sub-list automatically like that. In fact your query is likely to be returning multiple rows for the same person, because of the joins, e.g. if the person has multiple qualifications associated with them. To populate the `List<Qualifications>` you'll need to run a separate query (within the same stored proc if you like) and get a separate result set.

Comment: @ADyson I am pretty sure that the required fields are not null at all.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the pointing it out that works, post it as an answer and I will accept it. :)

Comment: @avirk done - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stored procecure only returns a single flat result set which will populate the principal properties of the class. It cannot populate a sub-list like your `List<Qualifications>` automatically like that. In fact your query is likely to be returning multiple rows for the same person, because of the joins, e.g. if the person has multiple qualifications associated with them.

To populate the `List<Qualifications>` you'll need to run a separate query (within the same stored proc if you like) and get a separate result set.